# ¿Como pasar un parametro de respuesta POST de laravel a Vue.js?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Tengo un metodo de Laravel que me permite crear un objeto y guardarlo en la base de datos.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request,[
        'id_ubicacion' => 'required',
        'id_tipo_inmueble' => 'required',
        'nomenclatura' => 'required',
        'descripcion' => 'max: 100'
    ]);

    $createdProperty = Property::create($request->all());

    return $createdProperty->id;
}
```

Como se puede ver, el método me retorna un dato.

Este método lo llamo mediante vue.js:

```
createProperty: function() {
    var url = 'properties';
    axios.post(url, {
        nomenclatura: this.nomenclatura,
        id_ubicacion: this.id_ubicacion,
        id_tipo_inmueble: this.id_tipo_inmueble,
        area: this.area,
        descripcion: this.descripcion,
        coeficiente: this.coeficiente,
        chip_catastral: this.chip_catastral,
        matricula_inmobiliaria: this.matricula_inmobiliaria
    }).then(response => {
        //Aquí debería atrapar el valor que me devuelve el método de laravel
    })
}
```

Hecho esto, necesito llamar el valor que me retorna el método laravel y poder usarlo en el el componente de vue, pero no se como hacer esto.

Comment: y si le haces un console.log(response)?

Comment: Si me funciono, sucede que guarde la información en una variable, e imprimi la variable, pero no tuve resultado, pero si funciona el response.data, muchas gracias

Comment: Axios tiene una estructura de respuesta donde el `response` esta compuesto por varias propiedades como lo son el `status`, lo que deberías hacer es obtener de la propiedad `data` lo que estas respondiendo desde tu back. en este caso `response.data.algo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La versión actual de axios retorna un objeto con los datos o con errores en caso de que los haya. `response.data` devuelve la información que necesitas junto con `response.status`.

**El objeto consiste en:**

```
{
  data: {}, // Son los datos con los que el servidor responde.
  status: 200, // Es el estado HTTP de la respuesta del servidor.
  statusText: 'OK', // Es el texto del estado HTTP de la respuesta del servidor.
  headers: {}, // Los headers con los cuales el servidor contesta.
  config: {} // Los config que se le dieron a AXIOS para la consulta.
}
```

Te recomiendo utilizar destructuración para utilizar directamente el objeto data sin escribir `response.data`. Seria de la siguiente manera:

```
axios.post(url, {...})
.then( ({data} ) => {
   // ahora puedes utilizar data directamente. Ej: this.variable = data;
});
```

Y por último, debes poner un .catch() después del then para retornar los errores en caso de que existan. Con algo como esto bastaría:

```
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar explicarme lo mejor posible.
Según estas mostrando en tu Controller retornas:  return $createdProperty->id;
Siendo este retorno tu Request que esta a la espera de ser recogida dicha respuesta por axios.
Entonces tu axios seria de la siguiente forma:

```
axios.post(url, {...})
.then( (response ) => {
  Tu_Var_Vue = response;
});
```

Donde Tu_Var_Vue puede ser una variable perteneciente al 'data' o tambien al 'state' de vuex. Asi recoges el valor retornado de tu Controller.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que necesitas es igualar tu variable con lo que traiga

```
response.data
```

Comment: Esto es la respuesta, pero el sistema la marca como de baja calidad debido a su extension. Podrias explicar un poco mas sobre axios y el objeto que devuelve? mira por favor el [tour] y tambien [answer]